# Is the quantization noise white here?

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, power-spectral-density

If I have the following power spectral density of the quantization error can I tell that quantization noise is approximately white? Can you please provide some justification?

[image]

Comment: I think white noise has a flat power spectral density

Comment: Can we consider this to be approximately white noise then?

Comment: see this question http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7678/determining-the-whiteness-of-noise?rq=1

Comment: Is the power in decibels or linear units?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your band-width of interest. If your band-width of interest is very very small than the bandwidth of quantization-noise then you may say that noise is white.