# How to check that the state observer works appropriately?

Tags: estimation, state-space, discretization

I have implemented a discrete state observer for a given dynamic system in continuous time domain in following form

$$\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k) = \mathbf{A}_d\cdot\hat{\mathbf{x}}(k-1) + \mathbf{B}_d\cdot \mathbf{u}(k-1)$$
$$\hat{\mathbf{x}}(k) = \bar{\mathbf{x}}(k) + \mathbf{L}_d\cdot\left[\mathbf{y}(k) - \mathbf{C}_d\cdot\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k)\right],$$

where $\mathbf{u}(k)$ is the system input, $\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k)$ is the prediction of the state estimate, $\hat{\mathbf{x}}(k)$ is the state estimate and $\mathbf{y}(k)$ is the system output. The above mentioned difference equations comes from the book *Digital Control of Dynamic Systems* from *section 8.2.4*. The state observer is intended to estimate the unmeasurable state variables of my system.

My question is how I can check whether the observer works correctly? At first glance it seems that I could compare the estimated state variables provided by the observer with their actual values but the estimated state variables are unmeasurable so I don't know their
actual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the error term

$$e(k) = \mathbf{y}(k) - \mathbf{C}_d\cdot\hat{\mathbf{x}}(k)$$

and [testing it for whiteness](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9080/80).

If the state estimate is good, then all the predictable component will be predicted and the remainder will be white noise (unpredictable).